# Find Single Interface IP address (libpcap)

Tags: c, network-programming, libpcap

I'm trying to extract a single IP address for a single interface, i've got this to print out all of the IP addresses for all the interfaces and tried to do

```
if (d->name == en0) {
    char myip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr);
    // print myip
 }
```

But it just returns null. I'm not all that familiar with C unfortunately, how can I extract the IP address based on the interface name?

```
static char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

void getInterfaces()
{
char myip;
pcap_if_t *alldevs;
int status = pcap_findalldevs(&alldevs, errbuf);

if(status != 0)
{
    printf("%s\n", errbuf);
}

for(pcap_if_t *d=alldevs; d!=NULL; d=d->next)
{
    printf("%s:", d->name);

    for(pcap_addr_t *a=d->addresses; a!=NULL; a=a->next)
    {
        if(a->addr->sa_family == AF_INET)
        {
            printf(" %s", inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

pcap_freealldevs(alldevs);
}

----Console:-----------------------------------------------
en0: 192.168.56.1
awdl0:
bridge0:
tun0: 10.20.30.40
en1:
en2:
p2p0:
lo0: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What is `d`?  What is `d->name`? What is `e0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char myip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr);
```

`inet_ntoa` returns a `char *`  (not a `char`), change to:

```
char *myip = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in*)a->addr)->sin_addr);
```

This line is also wrong:

```
if (d->name == en0) {
```

you want:

```
if (strcmp(d->name, "en0") == 0) {
```

Comment: Ah them pointers are always tripping me up, thanks it's working perfectly i'll accept as soon as it lets me :p